# How does commonjs make two copies during its export and require process?

Tags: javascript, module, commonjs

I'm learning about CommonJS from this [blog](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/javascript-modules-a-beginner-s-guide-783f7d7a5fcc#.yunb67c4a) and having trouble understanind the below in regards to the code:

> In this example, we basically make two copies of the module: one when
>   we export it, and one when we require it. Moreover, the copy in
>   main.js is now disconnected from the original module. That’s why even
>   when we increment our counter it still returns 1 — because the counter
>   variable that we imported is a disconnected copy of the counter
>   variable from the module.

```
// lib/counter.js

var counter = 1;

function increment() {
  counter++;
}

function decrement() {
  counter--;
}

module.exports = {
  counter: counter,
  increment: increment,
  decrement: decrement
};


// src/main.js

var counter = require('../../lib/counter');

counter.increment();
console.log(counter.counter); // 1
```

So if 2 copies are created, then wouldn't each copy have their own version of `counter` and `increment`? Thus each one would be connected to their own function of `increment`? The author is saying that there is 1 copy of `counter`, `increment`, and `decrement` that is in module.exports and another copy in the `var counter = require('../../lib/counter')` so shouldn't the `counter.increment` calling the `increment` function in the require copy and the `console.log(counter.counter)` return the connected counter in the require copy?

Answer (score 3):

I think the statement was made to bring about the contrast between ES6 modules vs nodejs CommonJS modules.Its not fully correct.

When you require a module here are some of the things you need to understand.

How `require` works behind the scenes ?

In short the module code required by calling `require` is executed and cached.
    Before the module code is executed Node.js will wrap it with a function wrapper ([module wrapping](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_wrapper)).This ensures that top level variables(like counter) are scoped to the module rather than the global object.This means that if you are exporting a function to be used in another module it can behave as a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) with respect to the variables declared within the module.Finally the contents of `module.exports` is returned.

How value assignment happens with respect to primitive vs object types?

Let's look at the `module.exports` of `lib/counter.js`.
You will see that it is exporting a primitive value(`counter`) plus two functions(`increment` and `decrement`).`counter` being a primitive value is copied by its value i.e the number 1 is being set as the value for `module.exports.counter` whereas increment and decrement(both being first class objects) are copied by its reference.In effect both `module.exports.increment` and `module.exports.decrement` are closures with respect to the `counter` variable that is used within their body. 
You can read more on primitive vs object assignment in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948809/setting-one-object-equal-to-another-object-with-the-assignment-operator-in-javas) post.

Finally inside `main.js` the `counter` variable(which gets assigned the contents of module.exports from counter) is a object with the following keys.

1. counter - which is a primitive value of type number.
2. increment - which is pointer to a closure.
3. decrement - which is also a pointer to a closure.

Thus you can see that the counter variable inside the functions refers to the one defined within counter module.And since the `counter.counter` value was exported simply by its value any operation on it has no effect on the original module variable.