# Set variable to an object array with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reference

I have an array of objects called `objectArray1`. I would like to set a second variable, `objectArray2`, to the value of this first array, and then be able to change it independently.

Here is the code I tried:

```js
var objectArray1 = [
  {number:1, color:'red'},
  {number:4, color:'blue'}
];

var objectArray2 = objectArray1;

objectArray2[0].number = 7;
console.log(objectArray1);
```

However, as you can see from the above snippet, changing a value in `objectArray2` also changes the same value in `objectArray1` (the `1` changes to a `7`).

I found some other questions on stackoverflow about this, such as [Setting one object equal to another object with the assignment operator in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948809/setting-one-object-equal-to-another-object-with-the-assignment-operator-in-javas), but they are all just about objects and not arrays of objects, so I haven't been able to apply them to my case.

To try and fix my issue, I tried some new code which I hoped would work better:

```js
var objectArray1 = [
  {number:1, color:'red'},
  {number:4, color:'blue'}
];

var objectArray2 = [];

for (i = 0; i < objectArray1.length; i++) {
  objectArray2.push(objectArray1[i]);
}

objectArray2[0].number = 7;
console.log(objectArray1);
```

However, the same thing still happens (the `1` still changes to a `7`). How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do a clone of this you just need to do

```js
var objectArray1 = [
  {number:1, color:'red'},
  {number:4, color:'blue'}
];

var objectArray2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objectArray1));
```

And this will actually create a new copy of the objects and not just reference them and you should be able to work on the separately like you want.

Answer (score 2):

U just need to use a spread operator.

```js
var objectArray1 = [
  {number:1, color:'red'},
  {number:4, color:'blue'}
];

var objectArray2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objectArray1 ));

objectArray2[0].number = 7;
console.log(objectArray1);
```